# Excel formula to compare two cells and select the one with smaller value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to compare two cells in Excel. Both have a certain value. I want to select the cell with the smaller value and use that in a formula.

For example:

- Cell `E1` is `961.454` and cell `E3` is `962.22`
- Cmpare `E1` and `E3`
- `E1` is smaller, now I want to reference `E1` in a formula, e.g. `E1-C4*D4`

Example data:

```
A       B        C         D       E
963.24  1.7      65.5      0.004   961.454
964.16  1.7      0         0       962.46
963.24  1.7      60        0.004   962.22
963.4   1.7      98        0.004   961.828
963.04  1.7      80        0.004   961.508
```

Comment: Syed, what you're asking isn't clear enough.  You say "when I get a smaller value", not when I get the SMALLEST value.  Also the relationship between the smaller value and using the next row in your calculation isn't clear and any answer you get won't assist you in this.  Until you provide some additional context none of the solutions will assist you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `=MIN(E1,E3)` to get the minimum value between 2 or more cells {`=MAX()` gives you the maximum value between 2 or more cells}

You can use `min` in your calculations: `=MIN(E1, E3) - C4 * D4`.

Answer (score 3):

The Excel function MIN() can be used to retrieve the lowest value.

```
=MIN(E1,E3)-C4*D4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
963.24  1.7 65.5    0.004   961.454  =MIN(E2:E6)      =F2-(C4*D4)
964.16  1.7 0       0       962.46   961.454          961.062
963.24  1.7 60      0.004   962.22      
963.4   1.7 98      0.004   961.828     
963.04  1.7 80      0.004   961.508
```

Comment: Check your formatting please, just pasting a block of text isn't really helping much. Could you [edit] and elaborate how this answers the question please?